# fancybox rel="group" don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox, jquery-ui-accordion

**Demo**: [Page URL](http://bilsalg-fyn.dk/biler/alle-biler)

We have integrated fancybox and jquery accordion on our side and it works.

Our challenge is that we want our accordion box to stay open when you click on the photo and fancybox opens. It seems to work now, except that our own script has affected rel="group" function from fancybox. See our script below. Are there any of you here who have an idea why this does not work?

```
$(".fancybox").click(function(event) {
    $('body').append('<a id="temp_fv" class="fancybox" rel="'+$(this).attr('rel')+'" href="'+$(this).attr('href')+'" >fancyview</a>')
    $("#temp_fv").fancybox().trigger('click');
    $('#temp_fv').remove();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You can see all the html, if you click on the page url!

Comment: Sorry did not even notice the link!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the nivo slider plugin is using the `rel` attribute to make the transitions between the pictures and it voids it for fancybox.

As a workaround, add the `data-fancybox-group` attribute instead like

```
<a href="http://billeder.bilinfo.dk/billeder900/1058700044_1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="group1" class="fancybox"><img src="http://billeder.bilinfo.dk/billeder150/1058700044_1.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: @AndreasSeierup : skeptic? check the source code. On the other hand, give `data-fancybox-group` a try. Believe me, I have seen this before ;)

Comment: For some reason `rel` didn't work for me, but `data-fancybox-group` did